# Gradle Build Failed -- Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

Whenever I try to build an apk using Unity. My gradle build gets failed. 
I get these 3 errors every time.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
```

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin\java.exe -classpath "F:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'gradleOut'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\Ashwin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.23\descriptors\com.google.jimfs\jimfs\1.1\22da77b0d76ea8df17298218f3ec1f87\descriptor.bin
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 17s
]
stdout[
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
```

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 3 errors
```

at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0020e] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:181 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:88 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: if you jdk is not latest version please update it and if its latest then go to your android manifest file and add this <application ...
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" > if not solved check this link https://answers.unity.com/questions/1301593/android-gradle-build-error.html